# outside vs out of the box

Tags: word-choice, expressions, differences

As a non native english speaker i wonder which one is the correct form to use ?

to think outside the box ?
to think out of the box ?

is there any difference in meaning ?

Answer (score 3):

Both can mean the same thing, although **"verb- outside the box"** is the correct form these days because of the excessive use of the **"verb- out of the box"** phrase in technology (software/hardware etc.) Latter more likely to mean that the subject succeeds to do the **verb** immediately after installation/unboxing. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_feature) link.